# The meaning of the 'module_name'

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

Click [here](https://github.com/michaelliao/awesome-python3-webapp/blob/day-05/www/coroweb.py#L158). 
In the latt of the code. I can't understand the 'module_name'. Where it comes from? what's the meaning of the 'module_name'?

```
def add_routes(app, module_name):
    n = module_name.rfind('.')
    if n == (-1):
        mod = __import__(module_name, globals(), locals())
    else:
        name = module_name[n+1:]
        mod = getattr(__import__(module_name[:n], globals(), locals(), [name]), name)
    for attr in dir(mod):
        if attr.startswith('_'):
            continue
        fn = getattr(mod, attr)
        if callable(fn):
            method = getattr(fn, '__method__', None)
            path = getattr(fn, '__route__', None)
            if method and path:
                add_route(app, fn)
```

I think the 'module_name' is related to the `class RequestHandler`. But i dont't know what it means. Does it let  `class RequestHandler` to become a moudle? Something like this?

```
import RequestHandler
```

Comment: Probably better asking this on the github repository issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't understand the 'module_name'

`module_name` is a placeholder of a value that's passed onto the function called `add_routes()`

For example,

```
add_routes(a, b)

# New Definition
a is app
b is module_name

n = b.rfind('.')
...
```

> Where it comes from?

In [awesome-python3-webapp](https://github.com/michaelliao/awesome-python3-webapp/blob/day-05/www/coroweb.py#L158), `module_name` is used only within `add_routes()` function.

> I think the 'module_name' is related to the class RequestHandler. But
>   i dont't know what it means. Does it let  class RequestHandler to
>   become a moudle? Something like this?

Consider:

```
# RequestHandler.py
def add_routes(app, module_name):
    print(app)
    print(module_name)
```

In that case you can use the code above by `import` like you mentioned:

```
import RequestHandler
a = foo
b = bar
RequestHandler.add_routes(a, b)

Result:
foo
bar
```

Comment: Oh, i forget print! Thanks!